# Up and download directly - no waiting

Tags: file-upload

I would want to program something where you upload a file on the one side and the other person can download it the moment I start uploading. I knew such a service but can't remember the name. If you know the service I'd like to know the name if its not there anymore I'd like to program it as an opensource project.

And it is supposed to be a website

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing sounds a lot like Bit Torrent.

Comment: But I want it to be a website so no one has to install anything

Comment: You shouldn't vote somebody down for not reading your mind about an unstated requirement.

Comment: @thomaschaaf  - sorry, I don't know of any tech which would allow that to happen.

Comment: The question does specify website.

Comment: WTF why are people voting this up? Its NOT BITTORRENT!

Answer (score 1):

You *might* be able to achieve this by uploading via a custom ISAPI filter (if you use IIS) -- all CGI implementations won't start to run your script until the request has completed, which makes sense, as you won't have been told all the values just yet, I'd suspect ISAPI may fall foul of this as well.

So, your next best bet is to write a custom HTTP server, that can handle the serving of files yet to finish uploading.

Comment: the weird thing is that I saw a site like this and can't believe they wrote their own http server

Answer (score 1):

pipebytes.com I found it :)

Comment: seems not to work anymore though :( anyone know a free alternative?

Comment: The obvious solution is to email them and ask how they did it, then

Comment: Paul it used to work and they don't seem to have the servers that they used to.. they want to get sold and apparently have it patented